# bind a control to a code-behind property of this object

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, controls

I have a property in a code-behind class to which I want to bind my Label control:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Label1Content = "some text";
    }

    public string Label1Content { get; set; }
```

But the binding fails. Obviously I am missing something in the binding configuration, but I don't know what. I know how to bind this property using C#, but how do I bind it using XAML and without declaring DataContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to declare a datacontext anywhere, you could use

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Label1Content}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You still have to declare a `DataContext`, even if it is the same control:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = this;

    this.Label1Content = "some text";
}
```

Also, the control will have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you can raise  the `PropertyChanged` event. You're property should be self-contained like so:

```
public string _lable1Content;
public string Label1Content
{
    get { return _label1Content; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _label1Content)) return;

        _label1Content = value;

        //However you decide to implement the RaisePropertyChanged method.
    }
}
```